# How to place links in django templates

Tags: python, django

VERY new to Django and I am a little confused.  I have placed a link in my html template file; however, clicking the link reports a 404 error.

App views.py file:

```
from django.shortcuts import render        

def index(request):
    return render(request, "login/index.html", None)

def terms(request):
    return render(request, "login/terms.html", None)
```

App urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path   
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name="index"),
    path('', views.terms, name="terms")
]
```

Offending code in index.html:

```
By signing in, you agree to our <a href="/login/terms.html">Terms Of Use Policy</a>
```

Clicking on the link pops a 404 error.  Any help would be appreciated as I learn a new framework.

Comment: `<a href={% url 'terms' %}>Terms Of Use Policy</a>` And configure `urlpatterns` appropriately. Django docs on this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/urls/#examples

Comment: With the above paths, you can *never* reach `terms` anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first problem is that both the path to the `views.index` and `views.terms` share the same path. As a result, you have made `views.terms` inaccessible.

You thus should change one of the paths, for example:

```
from django.urls import path   
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('terms/', views.terms, name='terms')
]
```

You better use the [**`{% url ... %}`** template tag [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/templates/builtins/#url) to resolve the URLs, since if you later decide to change the path of a certain view, you can still calculate the path.

In your template, you thus write:

```
By signing in, you agree to our <a href="{% url 'terms' %}">Terms Of Use Policy</a>
```

Comment: Thank you for clarifying this for me.  Worked perfect.

Answer (score 1):

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name="index"),
    path('terms/', views.terms, name="terms")
]
By signing in, you agree to our <a href="{% url 'terms' %}">Terms Of Use Policy</a>
or
```